# Read Field from another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, field

I I'm creating a TextBased Game while I'm learning java. I'm having an issue when I'm trying to read a field from another Thread.
Sleep Class:

```
package Events;

public class Sleep implements Runnable {

public int sleep = 100;

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        sleep--;
        System.out.println("Sleep: " + sleep);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (sleep == 50) {
            System.out.println("You need to eat");
        }
        if (sleep == 25) {
            System.out.println("You realy need to eat");
        }
        if (sleep == 10) {
            System.out.println("You'r almoust dying go to eat");
        }
        if (sleep == 0) {
            System.out.println("YOU'R DEAD");
        }
    }
}

public void PrintSleep() {
    System.out.println("Sleep: " + sleep);
}

}
```

Then I call the method "PrintSleep" from Menu class and should appear Sleep: 99 but appear Sleep: 100

Menu Class:

```
public class Menu {

Hunger hunger = new Hunger();
Sleep sleep = new Sleep();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String answer;

public void MainMenu(){
    System.out.println("Main menu: 1 Home, 2 Work, 3 Shop, 4 Nessecity");

    answer = scanner.next();

    if(answer.equals("1")){ 
        HomeMenu();
    } else if(answer.equals("2")){
        WorkMenu();
    } else if(answer.equals("3")){
        ShopMenu();
    } else if(answer.equals("4")){          
        hunger.PrintHunger();
        sleep.PrintSleep();
    }
}
```

Edit:
Sorry o forgot to put the some classes.
Human class:

```
public class Human{

Hunger hunger = new Hunger();
Thread threadHunger = new Thread(hunger);
Sleep sleep = new Sleep();
Thread threadSleep = new Thread(sleep);

Menu menu = new Menu();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

private String name;
int money = 100;

public void CreateCharacter() {
    System.out.println("Type your name:");
    name = scanner.next();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Your profile as been created with " + name + " name and " + money + " money.\n");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    threadHunger.start();
    threadSleep.start();
    menu.MainMenu();
}
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Game {

static Human human  = new Human();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("To start the game create your Human");
    human.CreateCharacter();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `volatile` modifier to the `sleep` variable?

Comment: You're never calling `sleep.run()` or passing it to a thread and starting that (which a `Runnable` would normally be used for). Thus the internal `sleep` counter is still 100.

Comment: You need to create a thread (using the Sleep class) and start it for the `run` method to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is that in your `Menu` class, you are creating new `Hunger` and `Sleep` objects, which are separate and have nothing to do with the `Hunger` and `Sleep` objects that were created and ran inside the `Human` class.

So you are creating a human and running his `hunger` and `sleep` through threads, but the menu doesn't see these `hunger` and `sleep`. It only sees the ones that it created itself, and they are not running.

When you create the `Menu` object, you should pass it the `hunger` and `sleep` objects from the `Human` so that it has access to them. So you need to change your `Menu` like this:

```
public class Menu {

    private final Hunger hunger; // Not initialized here but in the constructor
    private final Sleep sleep;   
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer;

    /**
     * Constructor that initializes the internal sleep and hunger
     * from values passed by whoever is creating and using it.
     *
     * @param hunger Hunger object passed from calling Human
     * @param sleep  Sleep object passed from calling Human
     */
    public Menu( Hunger hunger, Sleep sleep ) {
        this.hunger = hunger;
        this.sleep = sleep;
    }

    public void mainMenu(){
        System.out.println("Main menu: 1 Home, 2 Work, 3 Shop, 4 Nessecity");

        answer = scanner.next();

        if(answer.equals("1")){ 
            homeMenu();
        } else if(answer.equals("2")){
            workMenu();
        } else if(answer.equals("3")){
            shopMenu();
        } else if(answer.equals("4")){          
            hunger.printHunger();
            sleep.printSleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have a `Menu` class that can receive the `hunger` and `sleep` from another object, you need to change the following line from `Human`:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
```

To:

```
Menu menu = new Menu(hunger, sleep);
```

Now the menu that is created has access to the `Hunger` and `Sleep` objects that were created inside the `Human`.

But also change the `sleep` inside `Sleep` to be `volatile` or the `Menu` might not show it correctly!

```
public volatile int sleep = 100;
```

If you have a similar variable in `Hunger`, do the same there.

**Note:** I changed the name of the method to `mainMenu` instead of `MainMenu`, as well as the names of the other methods called inside it. Method names and variable names should always start with a lowercase letter. Only type names (classes, interfaces, enums) are supposed to start with an uppercase letter.